# Finding Dynamically created inputs

Tags: javascript, dynamic, input

Ive got a dynamically created field of text inputs.  The number depends on how many the user needs...

```
    <div id="dropdowncreate" >
        <div class="control-group" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; width:250px;">
            <a href="#" class="nav" id="adddropdown" style="width:200px;">CREATE FIELD</a>
            <div id="adddropdownarea" class="controls" style="margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px;">
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="nav" id="subdrop" style="width:200px;" onclick="addDropDown()">ADD TO FIELD</a>
        </div>
</div>

        <script>
        $("#adddropdown").click(function(){
            var elem = $("<input/>",{
            type: "text",
            name: "dropdown_[]"
        });

        var removeLink = $("<span/>").html(" REMOVE</br>").click(function(){
            $(elem).remove();
            $(this).remove();
        });

        $("#adddropdownarea").append(elem).append(removeLink);
        });


        </script>
```

When i want to select and cycle through all the inputs to find the ones named "dropdown", my script only finds the ones created while the page was loading, but not these dynamically created inputs..

```
function addDropDown(){
    var elems = document.newlog.elements;
    var len = elems.length;
    var dropdowns = new Array();


        for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
            if (elems[i].type === 'text') {
                dropdowns.push(elems[i].name);
            }
        }

    document.getElementById('ajaxfield').innerHTML = dropdowns;
    console.log(dropdowns);
```

}

How do i get the function addDropDown() to find the dynamically created inputs?  Basically, i want to find all the inputs in the form, i can handle sorting and filtering them - but this function doesnt even SEE the inputs.

---

OK.  So switching from Jquery to vanilla doesnt seem to solve the issue...  original script (to add a field) to this...

```
function adddroptext() {
            var dropdowntextinput=document.createElement('input');
            dropdowntextinput.type = "text";
            dropdowntextinput.name = "dropdown";
            document.getElementById('adddropdownarea').appendChild(dropdowntextinput);
        }
```

Succesfully creates the inputs, but still i can only find text inputs made on page load.

---

quite a bit of searching, but changing document.newlog.element to var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); did the trick.

Comment: What's this 'document.newlog' all about?

Comment: When you are using jQuery(?) before to create them – then why go vanilla JS all of a sudden when it comes to finding them?

Comment: also, I'd say it's generally a bad idea to rely on innerHTML. Either stick to appending elements with jQuery (for backwards compatibility), or use Node.appendChild ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild ) to add actual elements to the end. Building an array and setting it like that is surprisingly slow to run, and odd to read.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('dropdown_[]')` or `$('input[name="dropdown_[]"]')`.

Comment: newlog is just the name of the form.  i am newbee - used jquery because i found it - but your right, i should learn how to do it on my own.  I wrote the function to find the inputs - i was unaware of an incompatibility issue between the two?  I think for now, i am going to concentrate on learning to create the inputs with vanilla javascript - but am not sure that will solve the issue  we will see.

Comment: can you tell me why innerHTML is a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` in `DOM`

```
$("#findInputTag").click(function(){
    alert("You have " + document.getElementsByTagName('input').length + " input tag");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/N8YLa/)